# ms access database connection in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

What is the error of this code

```
connect = new OleDbConnection(coo);
connect.Open();
command.Connection = connect;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter ODA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Items where itemno = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", connect);
ODA.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

after I run it, this is what happened

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

What should I do?

Comment: is `Itemno` a integer in the database..? if so then the error is telling you the problem. `Strings textBox1.Text` is datatype `string` and `itemno` is `Integer`  so you will need to `(int) cast it or use Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)` this is pretty basic.. here is something you should read and keep at your Disposal as well [C# Basics - DataTypes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`itemno` is integer, that is why you are getting the error, remove the single quotes around the value. **But, More importantly, Use Parameters with your query**. You are prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
using (var connect = new OleDbConnection(coo))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Items where itemno = ?", connect))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@p1", OleDbType.Integer)
        {
            Value = textBox1.Text
        });
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter ODA = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        ODA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Couple of things to add:

- Enclose your Command and Connection object in [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).
- You don't have to explicitly open a connection with DataAdapter. It will open the connection to the database.
- OleDB uses positional parameter instead of named parameter